# DB Error: unknown error when trying to send mosaico civimail

Tags: database, mysql, mosaico

For a recently updated CiviCRM 5.56.2 + Drupal 7 (using mariadb 10.3), I got the little black box with the message "DB Error: unknown error" popping up when trying to send a mosaico civimail (e.g. as a test).

Weirdly, there was nothing helpful in the CiviCRM error log or the Drupal error log, or the sql error log or the apache error log!

I eventually discovered the error message in the browser console, which now makes some sense (since mosaico does a whole whack of js api stuff).

The error was hard to figure out because it was full of a long string it had pulled out of the civicrm_mailing table, but if I look far enough, I can see this:

```
Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '=']","type":"DB_Error"
```

I'm not seeing this in other updated sites (or at least, not yet ...), and I had run

```
cv api System.utf8conversion
```

Anyone with a similar experience or clue?

Comment: The api call doesn't update extension tables if they don't start with `civicrm`. If that's the problem, then you need to add the `patterns=table1,table2` parameter.

Comment: Good point, though not this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I reran cv api System.utf8conversion and now it works.